# How to get all documents in a specific range of time?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Like said in the title, im trying to get all docs in a specific time range. I have documents in my database with a timestamp stored.
I was looking for something like here [Querying CouchDB documents between a start date and an end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216868/querying-couchdb-documents-between-a-start-date-and-an-end-date) but i didnt really get it working for me, i also use nano for nodejs and i dont know how to write something like

```
?startkey="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"&endkey="1971-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

in nano syntax. I was looking for something here https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#dbviewdesignname-viewname-params-callback but i couldnt find something similair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`/db/_find`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-find) with a selector that uses operators `$gte` and `$lt` (or `$lte`) described in the chapter [Condition Operators](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#condition-operators) of the CouchDB API Reference.

```
"selector": {
   "myTimestamp": {
      "$gte": "2020-01-23T06:00:00.000Z",
      "$lt": "2020-01-23T07:00:00.000Z"
   }
}
```

With nano [`db.find`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#dbfindselector-callback), this could look as follows:

```
const q = {
  selector: {
    myTimestamp: {
      "$gte": "2020-01-23T06:00:00.000Z",
      "$lt": "2020-01-23T07:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
};

myDb.find(q).then((doc) => {
   console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, ill try that.